# Корректно оформить строку

Tags: c#, .net

Получаю из базы данных строку values. Она представляет собой числа через запятую

> 1,0,2,0,3,1,4,0,5,1

Первое число Id, второе - значение. (т.е Id = 1 - значение = 0, Id = 3 - значение = 1)

Эту строку мне уже далее нужно преобразовать в объект с первым типом Int, вторым Byte.
Я делаю это так

```
List<object> values_obj = new List<object>();
List<int> list = (mysqlReader.GetString("values") != "") ? mysqlReader.GetString("values").Split(',').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToList() : new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count;)
    {
       values_obj.Add(new object[]
       {
            Convert.ToInt32(list[i++]), 
            Convert.ToByte(list[i++])
       });
    }
```

Но как это оформить более правильно ( по-профессиональному)) ), посоветуйте пожалуйста? Не перечислять Id, значение через запятую, а сделать как-то так

```
{{"id":1, "value":0}, {"id":2, "value":1}} или {{1:0}, {2:1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код рабочий и тут мало что можно добавить, разве что может результат лучше иметь типизированный, например класс или Tuple

```
var str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8";
var res = new List<(int, byte)>();

var splitted = str.Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < splitted.Length; i += 2)
    res.Add((int.Parse(splitted[i]), byte.Parse(splitted[i + 1])));

res.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.Item1} - {x.Item2}"));
```

Вывод

```
1 - 2
3 - 4
5 - 6
7 - 8
```

Comment: А саму строку в базе может лучше изменить на строку такого типа, чтобы при необходимости изменить результат я смог быстро найти нужный айди? (Как у меня в примере)

Comment: @АлександрКиселев если у вас id и value, то нет смысла их хранить в БД как строку вообще, сделайте таблицу с 2 колонками - id и value

Comment: Можно и так) А как можно преобразовывать моим способом в массив, если строка составлена так `{{1:0}, {2:1}}`

Comment: @АлександрКиселев вы меняете суть вопроса, это уже будет другой вопрос - задавайте его отдельно