# Работа с object[] и List object

Tags: c#, .net

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();
list.Add(new object[]
{
     Convert.ToByte(1),  
     Convert.ToInt32(100), 
     Convert.ToString("test") 
});
```

Я добавляю object[] в List object. Как я могу удалить этот object[]?

```
list.Remove(new object[]
{
    Convert.ToByte(1),  
    Convert.ToInt32(100), 
    Convert.ToString("test") 
}); //Это не работает
```

И как я могу получить значения из List object -> object[] -> к примеру значение строки (я изначально записал строку "test")

Comment: Используйте Tuple вместо object[] или напишите свой класс для этого

Comment: @tym32167 Использую класс вместо object [], но все равно удалить не могу из List<object>

Comment: То есть у вас прблема с другим кодом, который вы не привели здесь?

Comment: Нет, я исправил как вы и сказали. Вот я пытаюсь удалить `this.cakes.Remove(new CakesSet { id = cakes_changes[i].id, value = cakes_changes[i].value });`

Comment: не, я вам сказал делать вот [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1037332/179763), а в вашем коде здесь нет ни класса, ни Tuple

Comment: т.е мне оставить List<object> а вместо new object[] использовать Tuple?

Comment: В примере, что я вам показал, нет никакого `List<object>`, забудьте о `List<object>`, он вам не нужен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В C# `object` является ссылочным типом, это значит, что при создание чего либо через `new` - вы получаете новый объект, с ссылкой которого вы дальше и взаимодействуете.

Написав

```
list.Add(new object[]
{
     Convert.ToByte(1),  
     Convert.ToInt32(100), 
     Convert.ToString("test") 
});
```

вы создаете новый объект `object[]`, ссылка на который записывается в `List<T>`.

Когда вы делаете

```
list.Remove(new object[]
{
    Convert.ToByte(1),  
    Convert.ToInt32(100), 
    Convert.ToString("test") 
});
```

у вас естественно это не будет работать, так как вы создаете совершенно новый объект, ссылка которого не будет равна той, что у вас в коллекции.

Для удаления объекта из коллекции, нам нужен его индекс, либо его ссылка, получить ссылку мы можем многими способами, хоть `var item = list[0];`, я например возьму LINQ и с его помощи удалю объект, внутри которого есть текст `test`:

```
var searchItem = list.Where(x=>x is object[]).FirstOrDefault(x => ((object[])x).Contains("test"));
```

В результате у нас будет либо `NULL`, либо нужная нам ссылка на объект из коллекции, который мы потом смело сможем удалить при помощи `Remove()`.

Что касается получения значений, то я думаю вы тут сами со своими костылями разберетесь, все необходимое я вроде вас уже дал. Ну а вообще, советую использовать что то, что менее динамично что ли, так вы сами себе палки в колеса ставите и делаете лишнюю работу.

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно работать с `object` и массивами такого типа.

Давайте я немного распишу то, о чём говорилось в комментариях.

Допустим, имеется класс

```
class CakeSet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Попробуем использовать его:

```
var cakes = new List<CakeSet>();
cakes.Add(new CakeSet { Id = 1, Value = "test" });
cakes.Remove(new CakeSet { Id = 1, Value = "test" });
Console.WriteLine(cakes.Count); // выведет 1
```

Мы добавили в список экземпляр нашего класса и попробовали удалить другой экземпляр с такими же значениями свойств. Но удаления не произошло. Почему? Потому что это *другой* экземпляр *ссылочного* типа. Их ссылки не равны - они разные.

Что можно сделать. Можно реализовать в этом классе методы `Equals` и `GetHashCode` таким образом, что сравнение экземпляров будет происходить не по ссылкам, а на основе значений свойств. Например, так (код автосгенерирован):

```
class CakeSet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(CakeSet other) =>
        Id == other.Id && string.Equals(Value, other.Value);

    public override bool Equals(object obj) =>
        obj is CakeSet other && Equals(other);

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return (Id * 397) ^ (Value != null ? Value.GetHashCode() : 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь вышеприведённый код сработает - удаление из списка произойдёт.

---

Другой способ - использование структуры (значимого типа) вместо класса.

```
struct CakeSet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Просто меняем в определении типа ключевое слово `class` на `struct` и готово. Заманчиво? Да, но не спешите так делать. Применение структур чревато многими проблемами. Если вы пока не знаете, как правильно работать со значимыми типами, то лучше не используйте их.

---

Другой способ, о котором тоже писали в комментариях: использование кортежей (tuple).
Это удобно тем, что не нужно создавать класс.

```
var list = new List<Tuple<byte, int, string>>();
list.Add(Tuple.Create((byte)1, 100, "test"));
list.Remove(Tuple.Create((byte)1, 100, "test"));
Console.WriteLine(list.Count); // 0
```

Тип кортежа определяется на лету. При этом он обеспечивает строгую типизацию (из-за этого единичку приходится кастить к байту).

Компилятор автоматически генерирует методы сравнения (которые мы выше самостоятельно создавали для класса) для кортежей по всем полям.

---

Ну и напоследок, кортежи значимого типа: `ValueTuple`.

```
var list = new List<(byte, int, string)>();
list.Add((1, 100, "test"));
list.Remove((1, 100, "test"));
Console.WriteLine(list.Count); // 0
```

Синтаксис ещё проще. Но, опять же, нужно знать их устройство под капотом, чтобы использовать правильно и без ошибок.

В одном коротком сообщении все нюансы не описать. Читайте документацию по структурам и кортежам прежде чем их использовать.